# Find all "and" combinations from multiple sets

Tags: arrays, combinations

Let's say I have `x` sets of objects, and each set has a certain number objects. I want create an array which will store all the unique "and" combinations of these objects.

For example, if I have 5 objects in set A, 10 objects in set B, and 8 objects in set C, then I know that there are 5*10*8 = 400 unique ways of picking one object from each set. But I want to actually store these combinations in an array.

So the array would be multidimensional, something like:

```
{
  { a, a, a }
  { a, a, b }
  { a, a, c }
  ...
  { a, b, a }
  { a, b, b }
  and so on...
}
```

I need the solution to as efficient as possible, because I am dealing with situations where there are potentially tens of millions of combinations. I am not exactly sure how to begin to approach this problem.

Sorry if it's not clear, but I don't really know what to call what I am trying to achieve, so I am just describing it as best I can. Thank you for any help you can provide.

**Edit: Here is some more information about the problem:**

The purpose of this problem is that I am going to compute a "score" value from each resulting array. Then, I want to find the top `n` scores and return them to the user. So actually, I believe that I wouldn't need to have the entire array in memory. I can just iterate through the array, calculate the score, and add it to the returned array if its score is high enough. That way, I only need the top `n` objects in memory continuously.

I hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: A couple comments: notationally, I don't think `set` can have the same element multiple times. Or, at least be aware that certain lagnuages (e.g. Python) will dedupe when you use their `set()`. Secondly - with 10s of millions of combos, do you *NEED* the entire array at once? Or can you iterate over each one. You'll probably run into memory-size problems otherwise, wouldn't you?

Comment: Hey, sorry if it's not clear. The objects in each set A, B, C are unique. If you are referring to the notation `{ a, a, a }`, what I am trying to say is `{ object a from set a, object a from set b, object a from set c }` etc...

Comment: Ah, gotcha, then ignore that first point. The second one still stands.

Comment: And yes, I am just going to iterate over every object in the array, so I don't need the whole thing at once. So would I write it to the disk or something, and then read it piece by piece?

Comment: If you don't need all the items at once, then you shouldn't need to create the entire array, no need to write/read it from disk or anything. If `A`, `B` and `C` each have 1000 elements, that's 1billion combos, but your program needs to only store those 3*1000 elements at a given time.

Comment: Hey, I explained what I'm trying to do in more detail in an edit to the OP. I hope it makes things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick python, probably can't get much more efficient, since you need to iterate at some point...

```
getItems(A, B, C):
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            for c in C:
                items = (a, b, c) ## or [a, b, c], as desired
                yield items
```

Or, if you're familiar with generator expressions:

```
gen = ((a, b, c) for a in A for b in B for c in C)
```

Then to use:

```
for combo in getItems(A, B, C): ## or for combo in gen:
    ## do stuff here
```

Edit:

```
def getItems(*allSets):
    if len(allSets) == 0:
        yield []
        return
    thisSet, theRest = allSets[0], allSets[1:]
    for value in thisSet:
        for values in getItems(*theRest):
            yield [value] + values
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I am familiar with this. However, is there some way to do it recursively? I do not necessarily know how many sets there are.

Comment: That last bit doesn't quite work yet; can't concatenate list `[value]` and generator `getItems(theRest)`, but I'm working on it

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the number of sets at design-time? If so, I would do nested for loops. If you don't know the number of sets, then you're potentially do some form of recursion to handle the looping.

With that said, I think what you're doing is, by definition, NOT efficient. Is there a reason you need to store all the possible combinations in memory, rather than generating them as needed on the fly?

Comment: For the recursion, you'd want an array of set objects (array of arrays in java, so on and so forth). Your recursion would loop through that main array, passing the index of which set to loop through, along with the currently selected elements that come before it.

Comment: Please see the edit, I hope it makes the problem more clear.

Comment: @Charles That clarifies a little bit. I would absolutely NOT store everything in RAM, under your situation. Just the top n scores, along with their score, so you can replace values as better scores come along. I would probably use a linked list or balanced tree, as well, so you can keep the scores in order and drop the lowest score, once you hit n items found.